# UrlFetchApp function truncates my api json call

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

This is the code I am running to grab assignments from the Canvas LMS API.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(canvas_link + "api/v1/courses?access_token="+api_key+"&enrollment_state=active");
var courses = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var assignments = UrlFetchApp.fetch(canvas_link + "api/v1/courses/" + courses[3].id + "/assignments?access_token="+api_key)
var assignmentsArray = JSON.parse(assignments)
```

It grabs the cources using an api key then requests assignments for those courses using the course id. Everytime I get the error that it Truncated my output. The `assignmentsArray` always returns a length of 10 when I know that there is more assignments in the course. And it will return less than 10 if there is less than 10 assignments.

I have tried using the `UrlFetchApp.getRequest()` function to get the request and put that into my browser it works and returns json for all the assignments.
I have tried adding headers and other options the the options for the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` to see if they did anyting, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does the api return object have a nextPageToken?

Comment: Sadly No. This is a link to the API Documentation
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/assignments.html#method.assignments_api.index

Comment: Well then it probably doesn't utilize collections and probably does not require paging to get all of the data so it must be something else.

Comment: Yeah, whenever I try to log any of the returns, it says, Logging Ouput too large. Truncating output

Comment: Yeah the logger does truncate stuff when it's too larger.  You should just capture it and display it with a textarea in a dialog and then you can transfer it to an ascii editor if you wish.